# Segments of letters

Tags: pdf

Now, suppose you have some text in pdf or word, and you copy paste it into latex editor or powerpoint presentation. Combination of letters "fi" and "fl" will not show and instead it would be inserted a new row. For example, in pdf you have "your task is to find all x such as" and when you copy paste it into the latex editor or powerpoint presentation it becomes this:

"your task is to

nd all x such as"

Is my computer the problem or is this a rule? If this is a rule, why? My brain is not enough to see why sequences of type "fi" is so special. Please help, that appearance hits my nerve badly.

Comment: Do you use T1 encoding?

Answer (score 1):

For the ease of reading, any good typesetting software will make use of [Ligatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature). Means, it merges letters to simplify reading the text:

[image: example]

(Source: Wikipedia)

Since these composite-characters are not recognized by your text-editor software where you paste it, it (apparently) replaces them by line-breaks.

If you're lucky, you might be able to use the "find and replace"-feature of your respective text-editor to replace these back to what they are supposed to be. 
Depending on how many occurrences you have, you might be better off doing it manually.